# Book suggestions for model validation (Gini, Somers D, Kolmogorov Smirnov, Kendal's Tau, Binomial/Adjusted binomial test etc)

Tags: kendall-tau, model-validation, model-risk-management

Any suggestions for books that cover topics such as the ones mentioned above?

The purpose is for banking, risk management, model validation of models such as credit risk and other types of risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Risk Model Validation: A practical guide to addressing the key questions by Christian Meyer and Peter Quell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906348510).

[The Validation of Risk Models: A Handbook for Practitioners by Sergio Scandizzo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1137436956).

Answer (score 1):

The Basel working paper contains quite a comprehensive summary of the types of metrics you are looking for:

https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs_wp14.pdf